# Android Studio 0.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated to 0.2.13 today then to Android 0.3 and all of a sudden I get these errors.

The error I get is 'Please specify an android SDK'. I have set the path to `Android Studio.app\sdk`. If I also try to load the SDK Manager I get the same error.

I'm kind of stuck how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I recently updated Android Studio, the SDK was no longer bundled in the app package. 
Download the Android SDK separately from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Then in Android Studio change the location of the SDK in the Project Settings

Comment: I figured! I had to download 0.2 manually and update directly to 0.3 without 0.2.13

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue. Open project settings and select SDK version from dropdown.